# How do I make a save system for a leader board with more than 3 stats

Tags: scripting, roblox

I want to make a save system so that people don't have to restart every single time they play

I don't really know what to do so I will show you the code for my leader stats this is located in the work space

```
local function onPlayerJoin(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player


    local gold = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gold.Name = "JumpBoost"
    gold.Value = 150
    gold.Parent = leaderstats

        local speed = Instance.new("IntValue")
    speed.Name = "Speed"
    speed.Value = 20
    speed.Parent = leaderstats

    local coin = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coin.Name = "CloudCoins"
    coin.Value = 0
    coin.Parent = leaderstats

    local rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue")
    rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    rebirths.Value = 0
    rebirths.Parent = leaderstats

end


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerJoin)
```

Again I don't really know what to do so, please help.

Comment: I have already tried tutorials online but none of them seem to work I know you don’t want to write scripts for me but if you could do it just this once it would rally help

Comment: Have you taken a look into the Data Stores tutorial yet? (https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Saving-Player-Data)

Comment: no I will do that now

Comment: I just did and I don't really understand what they said and what to change with the given code.

Comment: also I just realized on the first comment I meant to say really.

Comment: Just to confirm the parent of the script is the module script player data store and I dont need to call the normal script anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [Data Stores](https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Data-store) is pretty good. An important warning for testing :

> DataStoreService cannot be used in Studio if a game is not configured to allow access to API services.

So you will have to publish the game and configure it online to allow you to make HTTP requests and access the Data Store APIs. So be sure to look at the section in that link titled, `Using Data Stores in Studio`, it will walk you through the menus.

Anyways, right now, you are creating the player's starting values when they join the game. DataStores allow you save the values from the last session and then load those in the next time they join.

Roblox DataStores allow you to store key-value tables. Let's make a helper object for managing the loading and saving of data.

Make a ModuleScript called PlayerDataStore :

```
 -- Make a database called PlayerExperience, we will store all of our data here
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local playerStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerExperience")

local PlayerDataStore = {}

function PlayerDataStore.getDataForPlayer(player, defaultData)
    -- attempt to get the data for a player
    local playerData
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        playerData = playerStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)

    -- if it fails, there are two possibilities:
    --  a) the player has never played before
    --  b) the network request failed for some reason
    -- either way, give them the default data
    if not success or not playerData then
        print("Failed to fetch data for ", player.Name, " with error ", err)
        playerData = defaultData
    else
        print("Found data : ", playerData)
    end

    -- give the data back to the caller
    return playerData
end

function PlayerDataStore.saveDataForPlayer(player, saveData)
    -- since this call is asyncronous, it's possible that it could fail, so pcall it
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        -- use the player's UserId as the key to store data
        playerStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, saveData)
    end)
    if not success then
       print("Something went wrong, losing player data...")
       print(err)
    end
end


return PlayerDataStore
```

Now we can use this module to handle all of our loading and saving.

At the end of the day, your player join code will look very similar to your example, it will just try to first load the data. It is also important to listen for when the player leaves, so you can save their data for next time.

In a Script next to PlayerDataStore :

```
-- load in the PlayerDataStore module
local playerDataStore = require(script.Parent.PlayerDataStore)


local function onPlayerJoin(player)
    -- get the player's information from the data store,
    --  and use it to initialize the leaderstats
    local defaultData = {
        gold = 150,
        speed = 0,
        coins = 0,
        rebirths = 0,
    }
    local loadedData = playerDataStore.getDataForPlayer(player, defaultData)

    -- make the leaderboard
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Model")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local gold = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gold.Name = "JumpBoost"
    gold.Value = loadedData.gold
    gold.Parent = leaderstats

    local speed = Instance.new("IntValue")
    speed.Name = "Speed"
    speed.Value = loadedData.speed
    speed.Parent = leaderstats

    local coin = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coin.Name = "CloudCoins"
    coin.Value = loadedData.coins
    coin.Parent = leaderstats

    local rebirths = Instance.new("IntValue")
    rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    rebirths.Value = loadedData.rebirths
    rebirths.Parent = leaderstats
end

local function onPlayerExit(player)
    -- when a player leaves, save their data
    local playerStats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
    local saveData = {
        gold = playerStats.JumpBoost.Value,
        speed = playerStats.Speed.Value,
        coins = playerStats.CloudCoins.Value,
        rebirths = playerStats.Rebirths.Value,
    }
    playerDataStore.saveDataForPlayer(player, saveData)
end


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerJoin)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(onPlayerExit)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you this has helped and I have a better understanding of the player data save

Comment: yeah i can definitly do that.

Comment: Umm It stopped working and underneath the if on line 24 on the module script it says it expected ) instead of if.

Comment: Just to confirm the parent of the script is the module script player data store and I dont need to call the normal script anything